# Create IONIC UI with Tile like structure?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to create an Home page with items in tiles like structure,[image: EXAMPLE]

**HOME.HTML**

```
<ion-row responsive-sm wrap>
  <ion-col   *ngFor="let item of allservices ;let i = index " [ngClass]="
  {'col1':i==0}">
  <img src={{item.icon}} />
  <div class="myOverlay">
  <div class="card-title">San Francisco</div>
  <div class="card-subtitle">72 Listings</div>
  </div>
  </ion-col>
```

How can i generate the above structure from this code?

Comment: Each row will have 12 cols in ionic, give each column separate widths. col12 will occupy the full width and col6 will occupy 50% of width. refer this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create tiles like UI with \*ngfor in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240416/how-to-create-tiles-like-ui-with-ngfor-in-ionic)